# how to cast thrust::device_vector<int> to raw pointer

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I have a thrust `device_vector`. I want to cast it to a raw pointer so that I can pass it to a kernel. How can I do so?

```
thrust::device_vector<int> dv(10);
//CAST TO RAW
kernel<<<bl,tpb>>>(pass raw)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this using `thrust::raw_pointer_cast`. The device vector class has a member function `data` which will return a `thrust::device_ptr` to the memory held by the vector, which can be cast, something like this:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> dv(10);

int * dv_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv.data());

kernel<<<bl,tpb>>>(dv_ptr)
```

(disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled, never tested). There is a full working example of this included with thrust: [unwrap_pointer.cu](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/cuda/unwrap_pointer.cu)

Comment: Do we need to copy that data back? Now that dv_ptr has the modified data from dv, what do we do to copy it back to dv?

Comment: No, no need to copy it back, its just a static cast to avoid compile time checks. At run time nothing really changes.