# Converting Thrust device iterators to raw pointers

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm considering the following simple code in which I'm converting `thrust::host_vector<int>::iterator h_temp_iterator = h_temp.begin();` and `thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator d_temp_iterator = d_temp.begin();` to raw pointers.

To this end, I'm passing `&(h_temp_iterator[0])` and `&(d_temp_iterator[0])` to a function and a kernel, respectively. The former (CPU case) compiles, the latter (GPU case) not. The two cases should be in principle symmetric, so I do not understand the reason for the error message which is:

```
Error   1   error : no suitable conversion function from "thrust::device_ptr<int>" to "int *" exists
```

The configurations are:

1. `Windows 7`, `Visual Studio 2010`, `CUDA 7.5`, compiling for the `3.5` architecture.
2. `Windows 10`, `Visual Studio 2013`, `CUDA 8.0`, compiling for the `5.2` architecture.

**CODE**

```
#include <thrust\host_vector.h>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

__global__ void testKernel(int *a, const int N)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    if (i >= N) return;

    a[i] = 2;
}

void testFunction(int *a, const int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) a[i] = 2;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_temp(N);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_temp(N);

    thrust::host_vector<int>::iterator h_temp_iterator = h_temp.begin();
    thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator d_temp_iterator = d_temp.begin();

    testFunction(&(h_temp_iterator[0]), N);
    testKernel<<<1, N>>>(&(d_temp_iterator[0]), N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%i %i\n", i, h_temp[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just a very mild variation on this, isn't it ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/11113485/681865

Comment: In the thrust tag based typed model (the original model), any device memory is represented by a `thrust::device_ptr`. This has pointer semantics, but isn't a pointer, which helps enforce host/device pointer type safety. In your code above, the iterator decays to a `device_ptr` not a pointer. You must cast the `device_ptr` to get a raw pointer you can pass to device code

Comment: Thank you, talonmies, for your tireless help. I have solved the problem. Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: You could go ahead and write your own if you like. I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thanks. I have uploaded an answer with a fully working code.

Comment: This is an example of a question and answer which are better served by no MCVE. It just takes up screen space IMHO and the issue is clear with merely the kernel invocation one-liner.

Answer (score 5):

Following talonmies' comments, the solution is to pass

```
thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_temp_iterator[0])
```

and not

```
&d_temp_iterator[0]
```

In the following, the fully working code

```
#include <thrust\host_vector.h>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

__global__ void testKernel(int *a, const int N)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    if (i >= N) return;

    a[i] = 2;

    printf("GPU %i %i\n", i, a[i]);
}

void testFunction(int *a, const int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = 2;
        printf("CPU %i %i\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_temp(N);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_temp(N);

    thrust::host_vector<int>::iterator h_temp_iterator = h_temp.begin();
    thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator d_temp_iterator = d_temp.begin();

    int *temp = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_temp_iterator[0]);

    testFunction(&(h_temp_iterator[0]), N);
    testKernel<<<1, N>>>(temp, N);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you are using thrust, another prettier solution is to get the pointer with `data()` and cast it to a raw pointer:

```
thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_temp_iterator.data())
```