# How to create thrust device_vector from opencv gpumat

Tags: compiler-errors, cuda, opencv3.0, thrust

I need to convert a opencv::gpumat to a thrust::device_vector, then perform a thrust::copy_if , then copy the resultant thrust::device_vector to a cv::gpumat again.

**How to convert from cv::gpumat to thrust::device_vector & vice-versa?**

My code(below) gives compilation error:
**error: expected a type specifier**

gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

nvcc: Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44

Thrust v1.8

ubuntu 16.04

My code:

```
#include <thrust/random.h>

#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    cv::Mat input_host(1,100,CV_32F);
    cv::Mat output_host(1,100,CV_32F);

    cv::randu(input_host, cv::Scalar(-10), cv::Scalar(10));
    cv::cuda::GpuMat input_device(1, 100, CV_32F);
    input_device.upload(input_host);

    thrust::device_ptr<CV_32F> input_ptr(input_device.ptr());

    thrust::device_vector<CV_32F>   input_device_vector  (input_ptr,100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#ab7210166f4bd124855b520b3dde28fb1

Comment: the link gives an idea of how to go from the raw pointer to the gpuMat. I need to first convert a gpuMat to a thrust::device_ptr and then from a device_ptr to a gpuMat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to convert from cv::gpumat to thrust::device_vector ....

This cannot be done. Thrust doesn't expose a mechanism to construct a `device_vector` from an existing pointer. Copy construction is the only way that a `device_vector` can be instantiated from existing data.

> .... & vice-versa?

This can be done:

1. Cast the `device_vector` to a raw pointer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113590/681865))
2. Create an openCV gpumat instance from the raw pointer (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#ab7210166f4bd124855b520b3dde28fb1))

Be aware that if you let the `device_vector` fall out of scope, its destructor will be called and the memory which backs it (and anything else which uses the same memory) will be freed and you are in undefined behaviour territory.